# Android GridLayout and EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, grid-layout

one picture is worth ten thousand words. : ) The right corner is not displayed correctly. Thank you!

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="15dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

                    <GridLayout
                         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                         android:columnCount="2"
                         android:rowCount="2"
                         android:layout_weight="6" >

                         <TextView 
                             android:text="Blala:"
                             android:layout_weight="1"
                              />
                         <EditText 
                             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_gravity="center"
                             android:singleLine="true"
                             android:layout_weight="2"
                             />
                         <TextView 
                             android:text="Blalalallalalalalallaa:"
                             android:layout_weight="1"
                              />
                         <EditText 
                             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:singleLine="true"
                             android:layout_weight="2" />
                     </GridLayout>
```

update: weights
[image]

Comment: It appears that EditText is taking up the width. You could use column weights as you'd do in case of TableLayouts to make sure that the edittext is with in the view.

Comment: Thank for your comment. I tried this but doesn't work for me.

Comment: The idea is to mark the width as 0 when you use weight for any layout. Please refer to this link, http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#Weight

Answer (score 9):

Answer:

You can use next layouting:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:columnCount="2" 
>
<TextView
android:text="Blala:" 
android:layout_row="0" 
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" 
/>
<EditText
android:singleLine="true" 
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" 
/>
<TextView
android:text="Blal234243a:" 
android:layout_row="0" 
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" 
/>
<EditText
android:singleLine="true" 
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" 
/>

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either attribute can be applied to View's (visual control) horizontal or vertical size. It's used to set a View or Layouts size based on either it's contents or the size of it's parent layout rather than explicitly specifying a dimension.

fill_parent (deprecated and renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher)

Setting the layout of a widget to fill_parent will force it to expand to take up as much space as is available within the layout element it's been placed in. It's roughly equivalent of setting the dockstyle of a Windows Form Control to Fill.

Setting a top level layout or control to fill_parent will force it to take up the whole screen.

wrap_content

Setting a View's size to wrap_content will force it to expand only far enough to contain the values (or child controls) it contains. For controls -- like text boxes (TextView) or images (ImageView) -- this will wrap the text or image being shown. For layout elements it will resize the layout to fit the controls / layouts added as its children.

It's roughly the equivalent of setting a Windows Form Control's Autosize property to True.

Comment: try to manually set the width of your EditText fields, do it like this ... android:layout_width="160dp"(or something like that), and depending of your TextView width set width of the EditText.